# C: Reading int values from a file only results in first line of the file being read

Tags: c, variables, integer, output, file-read

I'm writing a function in C that reads int values from a given file and counts up by 1 every time a specified number is found. My .txt file being read has an int followed by a float on each line. However, my issue is that it only reads the first line of numbers and then breaks the loop. The part of my code that is causing the problem is this:

```
int tally(char fname[], int item) {
    int totalSales = 0;
    FILE *input;
    int intPlaceholder;
    FILE *write;

    input = fopen(fname, "r");

    if (input != NULL) {
        for (int i = 0; fscanf(input, "%d", &intPlaceholder) == 1; i++) {
            if (intPlaceholder == item) {
                totalSales++;
                // Adds 1 to total sales after finding a matching item code in the file
                printf("Has found a match!");
            }
            else {
                // Does nothing as it hasn't found a matching code
            }
            printf("\nLooped once.");
        }
        printf("\nStopped looping.\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("This option is not valid.\n");
        return 0;    // Could not open the file
    }
    fclose(input);
    return totalSales;
}
```

My current .txt file looks like this:

```
0   87.99
1   3.99
2   7.99
3   10.00
4   8.00
```

but my code above is only finding the 0 and 87 (it isn't supposed to find the 87 either but that isn't my main priority) by looping twice, when I'd expect it to loop 10 times.

I have a separate function that does the same thing with float values instead of int which works fine, I'm really confused as to why this is happening only with int values. Why is is doing this? Is there a better workaround I'm missing?

Comment: Go read the doco for `scanf()`. Using a `'*'`, it is possible to take two values (your input file) but only assign one of them to a variable. Hint: `fscanf( input, "%d %*f", &intVar );` Good that you are checking the return code already. Well done for that... (Probably failing because `%d` cannot cope with the decimal point after thinking 87 was a 2nd integer read on the 2nd iteration.)

Comment: @Fe2O3 Thank you for the quick reply! You're right about it not being able to cope with the decimal point I'm figuring out now, now it's just about finding a way to get around it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I indicated in a comment, you want `fscanf()` to "load" both the integer and the floating point value, but only assign the integer (in this version.)

I set up my own test data in a file name "test.txt":

```
3 42.42
3 45.58
7 47.47
1 78.23
```

And here is the code (without a lot of palaver.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int tally( char fname[], int item ) {
    int totalSales = 0;

    FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "r");
    if( fp == NULL) {
        printf("This option is not valid.\n");
        return 0;    // Could not open the file
    }

    int val;
    while( fscanf( fp, "%d %*f", &val ) == 1 )
        totalSales += val == item;

    fclose( fp );

    return totalSales;
}

int main( void ) {
    printf( "Test %d\n", tally( "test.txt", 3 ) );
    printf( "Test %d\n", tally( "test.txt", 7 ) );
    printf( "Test %d\n", tally( "test.txt", 4 ) );
    return 0;
}
```

And, here are the results:

```
Test 2
Test 1
Test 0
```

Using the `'*'` in the format specifier of `fscanf()`, the floating point value is "loaded" but not assigned to any variable. It should now be obvious how to sum the total of the floats without concern for the integer on the same line.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, I'm beginning to understand a little better about how format specifiers work--this did its job perfectly! And now I definitely know better for next time

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for accepting this answer. "Parsing" input can be a bit of a trick. It's handy to experiment with each of the format specifiers to learn what they can and cannot do for you. Enjoy the learning experience!